# error in upload image using php

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

code is to store the image nto the database
the database structure is

[image]

```
if(!isset($_POST['upload']))
  {
echo '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">';
echo '<input type="file" name="image"/>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload"/>';
echo '</form>';
   }
 else
   {
$upload='images/';
$name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
$tempname=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$filesize=$_FILES['image']['size'];
$filetype=$_FILES['image']['type'];
$path=$upload.$name;
$result=move_uploaded_file($tempname, $path);
if(!$result)
{
    echo "error";
}
$sql="INSERT INTO imaget(name,image) VALUES('$name','$path')";
if(($conn->query($sql))==true)
{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM imaget";
    if(($img=$conn->query($sql))==true)
    {
        echo "success";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "error in upload into database";
}
    }
```

it shows warning like this

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(images/20140302_210804.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\image.php on line 18

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php2923.tmp' to 'images/20140302_210804.jpg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\image.php on line 18

errorsuccess
```

why it shows warning and how to solve the warning anyone help me?

Comment: You can copy & paste the error text instead of showing a screenshot of it.

Comment: Are you sure you have an `images` folder?

Comment: ya image folder is there..

Comment: it has to do with the filesystem, not with the database!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why it shows warning?

Because it could not move the file move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php2923.tmp' to 'images/20140302_210804.jpg

Upload always put your file first to a temporary position, and then you are responsible to move it to the right position.

Maybe you should provide an absolute path in `$upload`.
If error still there, you can check your filesystem.
If error still there, use php file functions to see if php can read and write the directories.